# PHILIPS 247E6LDAD Full HD 23.6" LED Monitor with MHL randomly dims

Tags: display, display-settings, default-settings

So I bought a Philips monitor around half a year ago and it was working fine. However, in the past few weeks, I have noticed that the screen gets dimmer each time. I have seen it visually get dimmer as well as i am playing games. The only fix I have found is to restart my PC so I think that it is an Eco mode or something. I tried messing around with the menus but couldn't find anything.I not changed anything since I bought it except for changing the mode from **normal** to **game** The [link](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/computing/pc-monitors/pc-monitors/philips-247e6ldad-full-hd-23-6-led-monitor-with-mhl-10141120-pdt.html) is here. Also, i bought it from pc world if that is of any use.

Comment: Try changing it back to normal, or try other modes. I've got an led TV that does something similar in certain modes.

Comment: I've tried changing the settings but the others are too dark